# translation csv not visible

Tags: magento2, translate, i18n

I made a CSV. Name: 'nl_NL.csv'

Content: You added %1 to your shopping cart.,U heeft %1 aan uw winkelwagen toegevoegd.

That as what I want to Translate in Dutch as it is not in the standard language package.

I have put this 'nl_NL.csv' in /public_html/app/design/frontend/developer/mythem/i18n

I ran 
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -f
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento cache:flush

Still in English.... Rest of the site is Dutch, that is also the setting in backend.

Please advise if you know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: try to run **php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy nl_NL -f**

Comment: Did you place your text between quotation marks?

Comment: No just the text in 2 columns. No quotation marks. Should i?

Answer (score 0):

So solution was caching issue.

Our hoster implemented Varnish caching. Apparantly not set up fully correct.
Flushing Magento cache did not flush Varnish .

After we noted Varnish not working correctly they made changes and restarted Varnish -> translations visible.

In short. Always test if Varnish setup is working properly when you encounter problems like this.